# javascript onClick not working after Postback

Tags: html, asp.net, jscript

I am using ASP.NET, Bootstrap and jQuery to display and edit data.

The data is searched for and returned by ASP.NET code behind which updates an update panel around the controls which update the data.

I have a HTML button outside of the update panel which moves the Bootstrap tab from tab(0) to tab(1).

If I press the button before doing a search for data, the onclick event fires and I get warnings that I have not completed all of the required data.

If I do a search for the data and update the update panel, the onclick event doesn't fire.

If I click anywhere on the page and then press the button, the onclick event fires and moves to the next tab.

In Chrome, the onclick event fires correctly, even after the update panel is updated.

I have the following at the top of the html to set up the jQuery functions:

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(startUp);

</script>
```

The javascript is in a separate file, which I don't think causes a problem.

```
function firstButtonClick(move) {

    if (move = 1) {
        $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
    }
```

}

I added the parameter to stop the code being run after the update so a user can actually update it.

This is the code for the tab and button and update panel:

```
   <div id="mnuSupporterDetails" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                Supporter Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <%--<a class="btn btn-default btnPrevious">Previous</a> --%>
                                        <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="firstButtonClick(1)">Next</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppContactDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    Sys.Application.add_load(firstButtonClick(0)); 
                                </script>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label for="inpSupporterNumber">
                                                Supporter Number:</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpSupporterNumber"
                                                    placeholder="Supporter Number" maxlength="10" />
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSearchContacts" runat="server" type="submit">
                                                        Search</button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <label for="inpTitle">
                                                Title:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpTitle" placeholder="Title"
                                                required="true" maxlength="50" />
                                            <label for="inpForename">
                                                Forename:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpForename" placeholder="Forename"
                                                required="true" maxlength="30" />
                                            <label for="inpSurname">
                                                Surname:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpSurname" placeholder="Surname"
                                                required="true" maxlength="30" />
                                            <label for="inpAddressLine1">
                                                Address:</label>
                                            <%--<div class="input-group">--%>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpAddressLine1"
                                                    placeholder="Address Line 1" required="true" maxlength="60" />
                                                <%--<span class="input-group-btn">--%>
                                                    <%--<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnQAS" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdlQAS">--%>
                                                        <%--&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>--%>
                                                    <%--</button>--%>
                                                <%--</span>--%>
                                            <%--</div>--%>
                                            <label for="inpAddressLine2">
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpAddressLine2"
                                                placeholder="Address Line 2" maxlength="35" />
                                            <label for="inpAddressLine3">
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpAddressLine3"
                                                placeholder="Address Line 3" maxlength="35" />
                                            <label for="inpAddressLine4">
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpAddressLine4"
                                                placeholder="Address Line 4" maxlength="35" />
                                            <label for="inpAddressLine5">
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpAddressLine5"
                                                placeholder="Address Line 5" maxlength="35" />
                                            <label for="inpPostCode">
                                                Post Code:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpPostCode" placeholder="Post Code"
                                                required="true" maxlength="8" />
                                            <label for="inpCountry">
                                                Country:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpCountry" placeholder="Country"
                                                maxlength="42" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="inpTelephoneNumber">
                                                    Telephone Number:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpTelephoneNumber"
                                                    placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="20" />
                                                <label for="inpEmailAddress">
                                                    EMail Address:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control summary" runat="server" id="inpEmailAddress"
                                                    placeholder="EMail Address" maxlength="100" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a class="btn btn-success btnNext">Next</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1 ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache? As sometimes Javascript can hang around in Chrome and do weird things.

Cheers,
Definitely Not Mac

I accept apologies.